# Is 1KB = 1.024 bytes OR 1.000 bytes?

Tags: byte, size, bit

Everyone keeps saying that

```
1'000 KB = 1 MB (decimal) -> Megabyte (MB) 10^6 Byte = 1 000 000 Byte

1'024 KB = 1 MiB (binary) -> Mebibyte (MiB) 2^20 Byte = 1 048 576 Byte
```

But when you look at windows properties of a folder, you get:

[image]

Which clearly uses 1KB = 1024bytes (and it's not this "MiB" but still uses 1024). So, what's the veredict?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is 1KB = 1.024 bytes OR 1.000 ?

Yes, in causal discourse, it is either one - context sensitive.

- Memory size tends to use 1024.
- File size tends to use 1000.

Exceptions are common.

Else see [Kilobyte](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kilobyte).

Pedantic concerns like this include using `K`, when `k` should be used as in *1kB*.

Comment: It should be something more clear. I'm developing a system in which each user gets 40MB of space. But if I use ```1KB = 1.000 bytes``` Clearly the users will see that when they upload a file, like in the example, of 276KB, it will show that is occupying more space than it should due to the conversion of  ```1KB = 1.000 bytes``` instead of  ```1KB = 1.024 bytes```. So strange that it differs from system to system.

Comment: @Soulss "It should be something more clear" --> Yes, but we does not control the commerce language.  Programmers tend to like 1024 for hopefully obvious reasons, advertising likes 1000 as it makes for bigger specs.